# How to add stencil's IntrinsicElements to react's IntrinsicElements

Tags: reactjs, typescript, web-component, stenciljs

I am planning to use some stencil components inside a React App using the 0.0.0-experimental version, so I can use my components with `<kebab-case>`. I am rather new to typescript and would like to understand how I can add stencils auto-generated IntrinsicElements to my React IntrinsicElements.
What I do right now inside my React component is:

```
import React from "react";
import { JSX as stencils } from "stencil-project/dist/types/components"; // (I am using a yarn mono-repo)
import { defineCustomElements } from 'stencil-project/dist/esm/loader';

defineCustomElements();


declare global { 
    namespace JSX { 
        interface IntrinsicElements extends stencils.IntrinsicElements {} 
    } 
};

export const App = () => {
    return (<my-component></my-component>);
}
```

It works, but it feels like it's not the right way. Can you point me to some documentation or other helpful resources?
https://stenciljs.com/docs/typed-components tells me I can do it, but it doesn't tell me how.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add you components in `InstrictElements` interface like following:

```
// Some global.d.ts file.
// Importing React namespace is important
import React from 'react';

interface MyStencilComponentProp {
  myProp: number;
}

declare global {
  namespace JSX {

    interface IntrinsicElements {
      'my-stencil-comp': MyStencilComponentProp;
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your react components, you can do use like other native HTML Elements:

```
export function ReactComp(props: any) {

  return (
    <>
      <my-stencil-comp myProp={10} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Using the [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) feature of TypeScript, the `IntrinsicElement` interface defined by `@types/react` and your `d.ts` file would be merged into a single interface.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think this is what I am doing already by extending stencils.IntrinsicElements or am I missing something? My approach works, I just don't think it's a clean way to solve it.

Comment: Yes. Your approach works (and is the clean way) but one small change. I won't prefer to extend `IntrinsicElements` interface. Rather, I would explicitly add the elements.